# Jobrunr- Prevent multiple threads trying to execute the same job

Tags: java, spring-boot, jobrunr

Scenario:
I have enqueued a job and thread1 has started executing the job. Meanwhile, another thread2 queries the DB and fetches a job from the DB, and starts processing it. Thus the same job is being executed by 2 threads concurrently. How do I prevent thread2 from accessing that job if it's already picked by thread1?
Is there Jobrunr setting or any annotation? I am using Jobrunr without pro.

Answer (score 1):

That should not happen... JobRunr is doing optimistic locking so it tries to lock a job before it starts processing it. Only if it can acquire the lock, it will process the job. Can you create a Github repo that reproduces the issue and create a Github issue in the JobRunr repo?

Comment: I will recheck and come back to you.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing the same issue, I have observed this to happen too. I could reproduce it by simply clicking multiple times on schedule a recurring job in the dashboard. Until there is a fix for it, I advise you to mark your method as synchronized.

```
@Job(name = "your-job-id")
public void runYourJob() {
    log.info("start");
    BackgroundJob.startBatch(this::doSomething);
    log.info("end");
}

public synchronized void doSomething() {
    log.info("START");
    // YOUR CODE
    log.info("END");
}
```